# CodeMirror 3.x -- Is there an event that fires each time the linter completes?

Tags: codemirror

### Background

- I'm currently using CodeMirror 3.13
- I have multiple editors on a page (probably not significant)

### The Ask

I want to count the number and type of linting errors and display a summary elsewhere in the page. To do that I would like to know when the linter completes execution so that I don't have to poll for changes.

What is the event-based solution?

Thank you for your time! (I upvote all valid attempts ...that aren't obviously wrong of course)

### References

Here is my error counter snippet (coffeescript):

```
for eachError in doc.getAllMarks()
  numStaticErrors++ if eachError.className is "CodeMirror-lint-mark-error"
  numStaticErrors++ if eachError.className is "CodeMirror-lint-marker-warning"
  numStaticErrors++ if eachError.className is "CodeMirror-lint-marker-multiple"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the only way to be notified of a linting event is to set the `"lintWith"` option to an object containing an `onUpdateLinting` property, which is a callback that will be called with the list of linting errors/warning as its first argument whenever the markers are updated.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript linting in CodeMirror with completion callback

*Many* thanks to Marijn for writing the excellent CodeMirror and supporting it so well. This answer seeks to provide a complete explanation/solution (incorporating Marijn's answer above).

Specifically, the following features/requirements:

- Initialize CodeMirror
- Apply the included javascript validator (linter)
- Use the built-in linting interface
- Expose the linter's completion callback

### Initializing CodeMirror

In [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) (because it's clearer):

```
options = 
        mode: "javascript"
        lineNumbers: true 
        gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"]
        lintWith: 
          getAnnotations: CodeMirror.javascriptValidator
          onUpdateLinting: (lintErrorsWarnings) -> 
            # Do something with the linter's errors and warnings
CodeMirror $("#editor"), options
```

### lintErrorsWarnings Format

The linter's completion callback takes a single parameter with is an array of objects as shown in this example:

```
[
  {
    from: Pos
      ch: 0
      line: 0
    message: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."
    severity: "error"
    to: Pos
      ch: 5
      line: 0
  },
  {
    from: Pos
      ch: 5
      line: 0
    message: "Missing semicolon."
    severity: "error"
    to: Pos
      ch: 6
      line: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: "In CoffeeScript (because it's clearer)"  I'm sorry but it just isn't.